# Convert string to const char* (with binary data)

Tags: c++, binary

What I want to do is to convert a string into const char*.

Ideally I could just use "const char* myConstChar = myString.c_str()" but as my example below shows; it doesn´t work well for binary data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string myString;  // This need to be string
    ifstream infile;
const char* myConstChar;  // This need to be const char*

infile.open("binary.bin");

if(infile){
        while(getline(infile, myString)){ 
        std::cout << "Data: " << myString << " string length: "; 
            std::cout << myString.length() << "\n";
            myConstChar = myString.c_str();
            std::cout << "const char Data: " << myConstChar; 
            std::cout << " const char length: "<< strlen(myConstChar) <<"\n";
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This returns "string length: 13" and "const char length: 3".

Apparently there are some loss of data when converting string to `const char*` using `myString.c_str()`!

How do I convert a string to const char* without losing binary data?!

Comment: Why are you using a string to read binary data?

Comment: I suggest you switch to `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: How is it [tag:c] question? o.O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your binary data contains zero-valued bytes.  These are identical to null-terminators, which functions like `strlen` use to determine the end of a string.

It's arguable that arbitrary binary data shouldn't be treated as a string.  So use `std::vector<char>` instead, and don't use functions like `strlen`.

Comment: Or, simply keep it in a std::string, and use c_str() combined with length() to access the content!

Comment: Okey, there are a few zero-valued bytes in the example: hexdump -C ./binary.bin 
00000000  03 01 6a 00 00 07 56 52  03 30 00 01 01. So is it possible to convert it to const char* at all?

Comment: The issue with std::vector<char> is that eventually I want to convert the data into readable content. The custom library I use only take const char* as argument. Thus I would end up with needing to convert from vector<char> into const char* instead...

Comment: "I want convert the data into readable content". There is no possible conversion between binary data and strings. All you can do with binary is print them in the hex form, or something like that.

Comment: @user1432032: Yes; your code already does obtain a valid `const char *`.  The problem is that you cannot treat it like a string, because it isn't one.

Comment: Since it is "binary xml" I want to convert then there are possible readable conversions. Anyways to make it short: I made a different approach where data from the buffer where build into an unsigned char* (which I could easy pass to the converter) instead of try to convert a string. Why I used string in first place? In most cases I think it easier to handle...

Comment: @user1432032: if the data has nul bytes in it, then they're there in the input independently of whether you're adding them to a `string` or putting them in an array pointed to by an `unsigned char*`. Either way, if the resulting data has nul bytes in it, then as far as `strlen` is concerned, the first nul byte terminates the string. If your `unsigned char*`-using code works and your `string`-using code doesn't, then you must be unnecessarily conflating the storage used for the data, with the algorithm used to convert it.